# client side validation not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I can't seem to get client-side validation to work in an asp.net mvc3 application. In the config I have

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

In my _Layout.cshtml I have

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my page I have

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am just playing around using mvc 3 with ef 4 and my model class just has a field with that is required but client-side validation is not triggering.  It's always posting back. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the model that you're expecting validation for?

Comment: The validation does happen.  It just happens on the server-side.  It's not occurring on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using in your Model for validation?  Here is a quick and easy way:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace YourNs
{
    public class YourModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string SomeRequiredString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now in your view for this model, if you have the necessary scripts referenced there should be client side validation.  It's all through the `[Required]` attribute.

Comment: Currently, I am just using the EF generated classes. When it posts back it does validate the required field it is just that the client side should be firing and it's not

Answer (score 0):

I dont know is it feasible for your situation, but I get the validation by calling the .validate() function:

```
  var validator = $('#formData').validate();
       if ($('#formData').valid()) {
          //alert('valid');
          return true;
  }
```

Hope this could help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these `appSettings` are in your root `Web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```